# Coding Challenge for mock interview

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await

I have to do a coding challenge for a mock interview and am stuck. It's simple, so it's a little frustrating, but I can't get my head around it. These are the instructions

Front End Web Development Interview
We have a site to display albums from our jsonplaceholder website.
For this challenge, we're going to display the images from albums using the JSONPlaceholder API. You should be familiar with this API from past exercises.

Success Criteria
Functionality:
Albums load from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums and are displayed on the page.
The page displays the title property from the album
When an album's title is clicked, the album's photos are fetched from [https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/${albumId}/photos](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/$%7BalbumId%7D/photos).
The page displays the title, and the thumbnails of up to 10 of the photos for an album on the page after the album is clicked
Specific Instructions and helpful tips
The albums have already been fetched in App.js. Write the code to display the albums in App.js and the album details go in AlbumDetail.js.
Albums have this structure:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "quidem molestiae enim"
  }
```

The album should display the title
Each album should display the photo titles
A photo has the following structure:

```
 {
    "albumId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
    "url": "https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952",
    "thumbnailUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952"
  }
```

Each album should display up to 10 photos but not more
An album's photos should only show after the album's title is clicked.
The alt attribute for each photo's  tag should be set to the photo's title.
All information can be displayed on the same page

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import AlbumDetail from "./AlbumDetail";

function App() {
  const [albums, setAlbums] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums?userId=1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(setAlbums)
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  return <div className="App"></div>;
}

export default App;
```

This is the staring code I have. I have tried a few things to get it right. I made a click handler and set it equal to the provided url for images and can;t get it to do anything. Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: in the provided code, there is no UI.  you are not using AlbumDetail or displaying anything

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I couldn't understand what should be the final output. Can you check if this is it?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [albums, setAlbums] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums?userId=1")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(setAlbums)
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (id) => {
    const album = albums.find((a) => a.id === id);

    if (!album?.photos) {
      fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums/${id}/photos`)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((res) => {
          album.photos = res.slice(0, 10);
          setAlbums((prev) =>
            prev.map((a) => {
              if (a.id === id) {
                return album;
              }
              return a;
            })
          );
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {albums.map((album) => (
          <li key={album.id}>
            <span
              onClick={() => handleClick(album.id)}
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
            >
              {album.title}
            </span>

            {album?.photos && (
              //move these inside of AlbumDetail component
              <div>
                {album.photos.map((photo) => (
                  <img
                    key={photo.id}
                    alt={photo.title}
                    src={photo.thumbnailUrl}
                  />
                ))}
              </div>
            )}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I did all things in the same file.

demo https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-smoke-ui8ojp?file=/src/App.js:0-1579

Comment: It's still not passing the tests unfortunately

Comment: @poser67 What do you mean by passing tests?

Comment: There are tests for this. They are it returns the titles of the albums and it displays 10 pictures after the title is clicked

Comment: This is working but it is returning "photoTitle velit corrupti odio suscipit rerum". I think the phototitle should not be in the return. Any suggestions?

Comment: @poser67 I have no idea about that testing things, can you update the question with that testing result (better with images)? How do you test it, etc...

Comment: Sorry, I figured out the issue. They were looking for something in particular in the tests that were created for the interview. They were just testing that I was returning the orrect values.